# Cannot connect to SQL from DotNet Core via VPN

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, windows-firewall

I've tried solving this problem for days now, so I'm trying here to see if anyone have any more ideas to try.

I can connect fine to my local SQL Express, but when trying to connect to SQL located at two different companies with separate VPNs, I can't from .NET Core / VS Code / dotnet.exe.

I have this problem on a new laptop provided by my employer.

What I've tried so far to solve this:

- Checked the **ConnectionString** a 1000 times
- Tried from **my personal stationary computer** with the same applications and connected to VPN, **works fine**
- Connected from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, **works fine**, same SQL account used as in ConnectionString
- Checked server ports with PortQueryUI.exe: UDP port 1434 is **LISTENING**, TCP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): **LISTENING**
- Tried with IP in ConnectionString prefixed with "**tcp:**" and/or suffixed with "**,1433**"
- Downgraded .NET Core SDK to use **2.1.1** (same as stationary computer), down from **2.1.16**, same errors
- Opened outgoing and incomming TCP 1433 and UDP 1434 in Windows firewall
- Added VSCode and dotnet.exe to allowed applications in Windows firewall
- Both wireless network and VPN connection is set to "Private"
- Ran VSCode as Administrator (and not)
- Tried both User version and Computer version of the installation
- Verified that the ConnectionString in `appSettings.json` is actually used when running code (inspected while debugging)

ConnectionString format:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=<IPToServer>;Database=<DBName>;User ID=<UserName>;Pwd=<Password>"
```

Neither is a named instance, one is SQL Express, one is SQL Server.

Error without **tcp:**:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (1326): The user name or password is incorrect
```

But the Username and Password is not incorrect. I get that message from MSSMS when switching to Names Pipes too, but when changing to TCP, I can connect (from MSSMS).

Error with **tcp:**:

```
An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
```

Anyone have any ideas what to try? Since it's working from my other computer I'm pretty sure it's something on my laptop that's causing it.

Comment: Packet fragmentation? SQL Server is sensitive to packet fragmentation issues when the VPN's MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) is different than the underlying transport stream (ADSL, etc.). In "better" cases it causes slower than normal connections, in the worse cases it can't even connect and authenticate properly.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning But I can connect from MSSMS? Shouldn't that fail too then? Or is this a setting i can change in my code? It also works from my other computer as stated. Same VPN client used (OpenVPN Connect)

Comment: Maybe it's having issues talking to the SQL Browser service on 1434. If you know it's the default instance (MSSQLSERVER) and that it's running on tcp/1433 have you tried `Server=10.9.8.7,1433` in your connection string - where `10.9.8.7` is your server's actual IP address and `,1433` is the port it's listening on?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, as I wrote in OP: "Tried with IP in ConnectionString prefixed with "tcp:" and/or suffixed with ",1433"". Still works without any of those from other computer tough.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager on your local computer, the one where SSMS works? Open that and go to `SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration (32bit)\Client Protocols` and check which protocols are Enabled and what order they are used. There is also `SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration\Client Protocols` for 64-bit clients which may be set differently.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning All enabled and order: Shared Memory, TCP/IP, Named Pipes (Same for both)

Answer (score 1):

Final solution for me personally is found at the bottom in EDIT2.

I finally managed to get this working. I tried connecting to my router with a cable and adapter (took it from my other computer), no luck. Tried connecting to a mobile hotspot (my phone), no luck.

Disabled ALL not used network adapters (leaving only Wi-Fi and OpenVPN Connect TAP enabled), no luck.

Uninstalled Surfshark and it's belonging TAP adapter, uninstalled other OpenVPN software (not OpenVPN Connect), removed Surfshark VPN settings from Internet Explorer settings:
[image: IE VPN Settings]

And also checked "Automatically detect settings" in "LAN Settings":
[image: IE Lan settings]

VOILA! **Working**!

But can someone explain why? Even with all network adapters disabled it was not. Was it caused by the Surfshark VPN setting in IE?

EDIT: I installed Surfshark again (settings in IE stayed the same, no VPN, auto-settings), and I could not connect to SQL again.
After uninstalling I can connect. So it seems to be a problem with Surfshark, even when it's not even used.
I have it installed on my other computer though, so it's a bit weird.

EDIT2: I narrowed it down to a specific setting in Surfshark, Features -> Whitelister -> **Route via VPN** where I had selected just a few applications to go through Surfshark. After disabling that setting (all traffic through VPN) it is working again, Surfshark connected or not.